# Access input field values from form template in helper/controller classes

Tags: template, controllers, ce-1.9.0.1, helper

In a Magento checkout template there is a html tag for payment form:

```
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_testmethod" style="display:none;">
    <li>
     <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $_code ?>_cc_save" name="payment[cc_save]" title="Test" value="1" /> ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

From the helper class I'm trying to access this input field by:

```
$payment = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('payment');
$cc_save = $payment['cc_save'];
```

When the tickbox is ticked and posted, $payment & $cc_save are empty when logged.

This also returns empty data:

```
$payment = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

Why does this not work? 
How can one access values of input fields from template into helper/controller classes in Magento?

Comment: helper is not the place to check your post data. You have to do it in controller

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your reference

1. Your Form should have an `action`

Your custom form should have an `action` field for it. Action attribute determines which controller has to take care of the form action. i e

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/testPost') ?>" name="test-name" id="custom-id" class="some-class" >
               <!-- your inputs goes here -->
</form>
```

1. Use Magento's default validation methods.

You can use magento's default validation methods to validate your custom form. For an example for the above case, your form validation can be carried out by using this javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
        var customForm = new VarienForm('custom-id');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Here `custom-id` is id of your custom-form. Now magento will validate all inputs under you custom form, provided that it should possess valid class names. For example `required` class. If magento find this class for any one of input inside your form, it will check then this field is empty or not. If it is empty, Magento will automatically notify it. That means you don't need to do any custom validation codes.

For more information, go to this [LINK](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/)

1. Validate your form in appropriate controller

If you check your action attribute of form, it will somewhat look like this `http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/checkout/cart/testPost`. This means you need to validate your form in `cartController` which is defined inside `checkout` module and exactly in `testPost()` method.

So in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` define a new method (our custom method) `testPost()`

```
public function testPostAction()
{
    $params =  $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    //other actions comes here
}
```

Comment: How can I access the fields from the form in the controller action? Do I put a testPostAction() method in the cartController class? I want to access the field values in the form in the model when the form is posted. How can I call the controller action from the model to access the posted values of the custom form fields?

Comment: I have updated answer. Check it. You can invoke any model through your controller. For this you can use `Mage::getModel('Modelgroupname/Entityname')` and perform functions on that model

Comment: How should the input fields in the phtml template block be defined? Eg: <input name="payment['test_param']"/>  what would the params object look like in the controller action? How do I access its value. Is it like this: $params['test_param']?

Comment: Do I need a submit button in the form? If so I can't use that since the payment form block is part of step which uses the default Continue button...How can I post my input fields after the post is done via Magento's default Place Order button?